# Using put inside anonymous function callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am implementing [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) into my React+Redux Saga application, but I am having a few problems with some callbacks where I can not hit the `put(...)` methods. Using `console.log(...)` etc. in the methods does show, but I am not able to `put` to the state of my application.

I could be wrong on some of the implementation of async/generator functions, but I am pretty much stuck right now.

My code to illustrate what will not fire:

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

// Pusher actions
export const pusherConnecting = () => {
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.PUSHER_CONNECTING
    }
};

export const pusherConnectSucceeded = (client) => {
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.PUSHER_CONNECT_SUCCEEDED,
        client: client
    }
};

const pusherConnectFailed = (exception) => {
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.PUSHER_CONNECT_FAILED,
        message: exception
    }
};

// Pusher Saga
function * connectPusher(action) {
    try {
        const pusher = yield call(Api.connectPusher, action.directory, function(subscription) {
            subscription.bind(PUSHER_BIND_RELOAD, function() {
                location.reload(true);
            });

            subscription.bind(PUSHER_BIND_REQUEST_DATA, function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    put(updateDirectory(data));
                } else {
                    put(requestDirectory(action.directory.id));
                }
            });
        });

        pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
            put(pusherConnectSucceeded(pusher));
        });

        yield put(pusherConnecting());

    } catch (e) {
        yield put(pusherConnectFailed(e));
    }
}

export default function * pusherSaga() {
    yield * takeLatest(ActionTypes.DIRECTORY_FETCH_SUCCEEDED, connectPusher);
}



// My Api.ConnectPusher
export function * connectPusher(directory, subscription) {
    var pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_KEY, {
        encrypted: true
    });

    var channels = ["test1", "test2"  ];

    for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
        // Take each channel and callback with the subscription
        yield subscription(pusher.subscribe(channels[i]));
    }

    return pusher;
}
```

Solution based on @Sebastien

```
yield put(yield onConnect(pusher));

function onConnect(pusher) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
            resolve(pusherConnectSucceeded(pusher));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What does "is not hit" mean? You don't reach that line? How are you checking, with a debugger?

Comment: It means that I am unable to fire this method. The `put`method is not invoked in my anonymous method callback. Or maybe it is, but the state is not changing (which is my my question).

Comment: Why "maybe"? It seems like that would be a **really** fundamental thing to determine, whether `put` is not being reached or being reached but not having the desired effect. I'd use a debugger to follow what, exactly, happens, or (and this is **very much** a second-class option) throw in some `console.log`s. (But compared to wandering about with a `console.log` torch, using a debugger is like turning on the lights.)

Comment: My problem is that e.g. the `put(pusherConnectSucceeded(pusher));` method does not dispatch a state change. Apperently it is not possible to call `put(...)` inside an anonymous callback.

Comment: No, there's no way for `put` to know you're calling it from an anonymous callback, and even if there were, there's nothing special about anonymous callbacks. Again, you'll just need to debug this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redux-saga does not permit to `put` without using keyword `yield`. The put creates a simple json object/effect that must be interpreted/executed, and it won't if you don't yield.

Also, even with `yield put(...)`, if this is done in a callback, it won't be interpreted, because Redux-saga does not have the ability to run callbacks in its interpreter. They'll simply be run as normal callbacks and nothing will happen.

If `subscription.bind` is supposed to return a single result, you can instead wrap that call into a function that returns a promise, and then yield that promise.

If `subscription.bind` is supposed to return a stream of results, you might need instead of create a [channel](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html). I guess in the future someone will ship something that can easily permits to transform Observables to Redux-saga streams

Note that if you don't need to unsubscribe/resubscribe multiple times, it may be simpler to you to put this code outside the saga, and just do

```
        subscription.bind(PUSHER_BIND_RELOAD, function() {
            location.reload(true);
        });

        subscription.bind(PUSHER_BIND_REQUEST_DATA, function(data) {
            if (data) {
                reduxStore.dispatch(updateDirectory(data));
            } else {
                reduxStore.dispatch((requestDirectory(action.directory.id));
            }
        });
```

Comment: **THIS** is what I needed to know. I'll work out a solution and update my answer with a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you provide a simple example on the "If subscription.bind is supposed to return a single result, you can instead wrap that call into a function that returns a promise, and then yield that promise"?

Comment: Updated my question with my solution, you think this is good enough?

Comment: I don't know Pusher API so it's a bit hard for me to know. You can do `yield onConnect(pusher); yield put(pusherConnected())`. The first yield will block until connection is done, the second will dispatch event. I don't know if your syntax of embedding yield inside another yield works but I think it does too. But I find my version more explicit and flexible